# Make sure Excel file cannot be saved if the column has empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I want to enforce entering the values in a certain column, up to the point where there are values in an adjacent left column A. It would be ideal to avoid popups but instead, have the cell borders indicate that the value should be set.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a VBA macro.

Example: Make cell B3 mandatory for completion in a workbook before saving.

1. Open the worksheet in Excel.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA for Excel.
3. Double click on `ThisWorkbook` in the left pane.
4. On your top right pane select the first drop down arrow and choose `Workbook`
5. Select the second drop down arrow and choose `BeforeSave`
6. Enter the following code:

   ```
   If Cells(3, 2).Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "Cell B3 requires user input"
   Cancel = True
   End If
   ```
7. Save the Macro by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
8. To return to Excel press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>Q</kbd>.
9. Save the workbook (For Excel 2007 and higher save as `.xlsm`)
   and it will prompt you to fill in B3 before saving.

[image]

Comment: For testing a range of columns use this test : `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A38:P38")) = 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks, I've already found this answer elsewhere. My but real trouble is how to enable that each cell within a certain column is checked, not only a single cell.
For example, let's say I have a sheet with 7 columns, out of which the first three are mandatory. I'd like to have cells in t

Comment: Seems too easy, as this only requires a modification of the IF condition.